# Какие базы данных документов (NoSQL) сейчас работают в России?

Tags: база-данных, nosql

База нужна для учебного проекта, поэтому ищу бесплатную. MongoDb Atlas, Amazon(AWS EC2), Planetscale не работают. Сделала пока что проект на локальной MongoDb, но для того, чтобы запустить с Render.com нужно что-то с сервером. Буду благодарна за любую информацию, т.к. всё что мне советовали мои зарубежные однокурсники у нас не работает.